# Prevent imported pictures from evaluating

Tags: evaluation, image

When I insert a picture into Mathematica through Ctrl+V, and then later evaluate the whole notebook, then the picture evaluates as well, printing out the same picture. So basically I get duplicates of the pictures I have.

Is there a way to do so pictures cannot evaluate?

Comment: Have you tried [appending a semicolon at the end of the cell containing the picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DIVwq.png)?

Comment: If the pictures are just for illustration purposes, paste them into a text cell rather than an input cell.

Comment: In the `JournalArticle` `StyleSheet` one finds the style `Figure`, which is exactly for such purposes. It is not only impossible to evaluate, but is also automatically placed in the page center, and can be later numbered through the built-in system. This `StyleSheet`, however, may be not what you like to use for the everyday work for one reason. This is my case. Therefore, I made a default style for myself, where I included the style `Figure` taken from the `StyleSheet` `JournalArticle` as well as few other useful styles.

Comment: Optionally, you can select the cell, go to Cell->Cell Properties-> and uncheck Evaluatable.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to include illuminating graphics in a notebook, like vector drawings made with a suitable application, say, in .png or .jpg or any format that Mathematica can handle. Start a new cell and choose Insert > Picture > From file .... Now every time you execute Evaluate Notebook the cell with these pictures will also be evaluated and insert extra copies on your screen to the ones from the first evaluation. You can prevent this by unchecking Cell > Properties > Evaluatable. Another way of achieving the same result is preceding or following up the cell with the drawing with a cell containing text (a text cell) and then selecting both and choosing Cells > Merge Cells.

Comment: Can you please improve your answer offering more details on how what you suggest work and how it relate to the other answers offered in the comments?
Read about [How to write a good answe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). *Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.*